# PHP object overlapping

Tags: php, singleton, instance

my question is as follow:

I have several classes, I instantiate a class, then access some method from another class to get a response(return object), 
then access a method from the first class that return true or false, then I print_r the first object but it have been replaced (overwriten) by the data fetched with the query used by the second object. Note that the first class uses the same method from the second class to return his own result. Whats is happening?
note: the DB class uses a sigleton pattern for instantiate the class and makea connection to the database,

```
private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') , Config::get('mysql/username') , Config::get('mysql/password'));

    }   catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
    $user = new User();
$autos = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM autos");
```

this method uses a method from DB, the "query" method

```
   if ($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
                                echo '<br><a href="administrador.php">admin panel</a>';

                        }
    print_r($autos)
```

when I print_r $autos there is no auto but the object result from 
$user->hasPermission('admin'),
getInstance

```
public static function getInstance ( ) {
    if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB( );
    }
        return self::$_instance;
}
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;
```

Comment: Could you post the implementation of the User class? If DB::getInstance() returns pdo instance then I can't see why this would be happening.

Comment: Second object? How can there be a second object if you have a singleton object design?

Comment: Try to `$auto = DB::getInstance();` then var_dump it and see if it returns the correct results

Comment: Whats the result of print_r($user->hasPermission('admin')); ? false?

Comment: this is how getInstance works: public static function getInstance ( ) {
  if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
   self::$_instance = new DB( );
  }
   return self::$_instance;
 }

Comment: It seems like everytime it returns the same object in the singleton pattern, in the getInstance method returns allways the same DB object that is stored in the private  variable _instance, also it returns other variables that is where there are stored my results, I seems this is the reason because it overwrite all the variables used in the method query()

Comment: Maybe this works `$auto = DB::getInstance(); $res = $auto->query('SELECT * FROM autos');` then var_dump `$res`. You can also try  `method_exists($auto, 'query');`